# Shorthand to define variable when zero is a possibility

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a parcheesi game in order to learn node.

This is one of the variables I set on my class constructor:

```
var currentTurn = options.startingTurn || utils.randomize(0, realNumberOfPlayers - 1);
```

Basically, what it does is that it gets the value from the options parameter, but if I don't pass it then it will just use a random turn.

The problem is that if I pass a zero on `options.startingTurn` the first half of the boolean expression will be false.

How can I represent this without doing something log like:

```
currentTurn = (options.startingTurn !== undefined) ? options.startingTurn : utils.randomize(0, realNumberOfPlayers - 1);
```

Comment: you can't. the "pipe trick" works by using the left side if it's not a falsey type. Only way to get around it is by doing exactly what you did in your 2nd code. It's the double-edged sword of loosely typed languages

Comment: okay i lied. one way you "can" do this is to restructure your code to not let 0 be a possible value. You can use something else to represent it like '-1' or 'x' or 'zero' or something. Then you can do the above - at the expense of having to translate that 'placeholder' to the 0 you really want

Comment: It's the index of an array, so no, I can't. Guess I'll have to go with the long syntax declaration. Thanks-